# How to display microchart's pie chart labels evenly in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a budget app and i am using microchart's pie chart to display spending by category but the labels cluster to the right and leave only three on the left, is there a way the two sides have even amount of labels on each side?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tclL.jpg)

i added the chart entries and expected the labels to display evenly.

Comment: Three optional LabelMode for legend positioning : LeftAndRight(default), RightOnly, None. None of them can evenly distribute the legend at two sides. As an alternative, you may try ```LabelMode=LabelMode.RightOnly```.  Also, you could raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/microcharts-dotnet/Microcharts/issues).

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT alright then, I'll raise an issue. thank you.

Comment: I see the issue you raised on Github: [Pie chart doesn't distribute legend evenly on both sides](https://github.com/microcharts-dotnet/Microcharts/issues/329). We could follow it.